# Error encountered when using nextjs-breadcrumbs on NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, breadcrumbs

I am trying to add a breadcrumb component with `nextjs-breadcrumbs`. But it gives me the error as follows:

```
- error ..\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js (146:14) @ Object.useRouter
- error Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted
null
```

I have zero idea how to fix this.

I tried importing `useRouter` from `'next/router'` into the `layout.tsx` or `page.tsx`, still not working.

Am using Next.js 13 and Typescript.

Comment: Can you show the code you have got so we have a [minimal, reproducible, example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?